# Ubuntu 19.10 won't boot up

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, windows, uefi

Model: Lenovo Ideapad L340
OS: Ubuntu 19.10

I was trying to install Windows 10 from USB But I get "Windows cannot be installed to this disk due to GPT partition style" error

I found out that I needed to convert partitions to mbr but that would erase data so I searched for another solution and I tried some things through command
the last commands I tried was

```
bootrec /rebuildbcd
bootrec /fixboot
```

and then it died
when I try to boot up I get this error then it restarts itself automatically

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzRwj.jpg)

how can i at least get ubuntu back running?

Comment: There is no error I can see in that picture. ...about Ubuntu, you could try [boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows).

Comment: i don't have access to a ubuntu usb right now

Comment: "i don't have access to a ubuntu usb right now " Who said you must do it right now? Tomorrow is fine.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, I understand that you have only one computer and it is not booting. We can't help you until you get a bootable USB or CD, look for an Ubuntu installer or a way to restore any OS on your computer.

Comment: I have windows 10 installation media on my usb can I fix the problem with it?